# Is there a way in R to count the number of substrings in a string enclosed in square brackets, all substrings are separated by commas and are quoted?

Tags: r, string, character

['ax', 'byc', 'crm', 'dop']

This is a character string, and I want a count of all substrings, ie 4 here as output. Want to do this for the entire column containing such strings.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2):

We may use `str_count`

```
library(stringr)
str_count(str1, "\\w+")
[1] 4
```

---

Or may also extract the alpha numeric characters into a `list` and get the `lengths`

```
lengths(str_extract_all(str1, "[[:alnum:]]+"))
```

If it is a data.frame column, extract the column as a vector and apply `str_count`

```
str_count(df1$str1, "\\w+")
```

#### data

```
 str1 <- "['ax', 'byc', 'crm', 'dop']"
df1 <- data.frame(str1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few base R approaches.  We use the 2 row input defined reproducibly in the Note at the end.  No packages are used.

```
lengths(strsplit(DF$b, ","))
## [1] 4 4

nchar(gsub("[^,]", "", DF$b)) + 1
## [1] 4 4

count.fields(textConnection(DF$b), ",")
## [1] 4 4
```

### Note

```
DF <- data.frame(a = 1:2, b = "['ax', 'byc', 'crm', 'dop']")
```